# pypodio2 filter items by known field names and values

Tags: python, podio

I have a field in an app that I am trying to filter by. I can get filtering to work for *other* fields (though unintuitively). The field I want to filter on is called 'Client/Partner' so my request looks like:

```
c.Item.filter(app_id, attributes={
'limit':500,'filters':{field_id:{'Client/Partner':'Foo'}
})
```

Where Foo is the name of a client and it is itself an item from another app. I get the following error:

TransportException(response, data)
...
(object): must be array","error":"invalid_value"}

How do I go about grabbing arbitrary items from Podio where I know the name and values of certain fields? The way I thought this works doesn't seem to be working for me. Do I need the 'field id'?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the `field_id/external_id` of the field 'Client/Partner' as key and the `item_id` of item 'Foo' as value in an array to obtain this.

```
    searchResp= c.Item.filter(app_id, attributes={
                'limit': 500, 'filters': {'external_id': [item_id]}})

     // external_id is the external_id of field "Client/Partner"
    // item_id is the item_id of "Foo"
```